# How to list children pages of a nuxt.js nested route on the parent page?

Tags: nuxt.js

Is it possible to query for a parent's children or nested routes?  An example might be a blog site with this structure:

- `/blog.vue` (parent page)

  - `/blog/article1.vue`
  - `/blog/article2.vue`
- etc. The `blog.vue` might or might not make use of `<nuxt-child\>`.

**How can `blog.vue` programmatically list its children pages, or nested routes, so that a menu or table-of-contents containing links and titles for navigating to those children can be displayed?**

The [`<nuxt-child>`](https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-nuxt-child) documentation mentions that the nuxt router has a children property for routes. That seems to be accessible at `this.$router.options.routes`. Is there a better way?

Comment: Note that the nuxt/content module is now available (as of 2020) and handles many scenarios where the original question would have been relevant. https://content.nuxtjs.org/

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully someone comes along with better answer, but in meantime, something like this works:

```js
data () {
  return {
    nestedRoutes: []
  }
},
created () {
  this.$router.options.routes.forEach((routeOption) => {
    if (routeOption.path.startsWith(this.$route.path)) {
      this.nestedRoutes.push({
        name: routeOption.name,
        path: routeOption.path,
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access child component by the relative route so the best solution for handling it is `_slug` dynamic routes,

```
//// for example 

pages/
--| _blog/
-----| index.vue
-----| article1.vue
-----| article2.vue
--| users/
-----| _id.vue
--|
```

Comment: My question is how to programmatically get the the list of dynamic routes so that a list of all the dynamic routes, or children, can be rendered as hrefs in the index page.